# Move Multiple Workbooks in Excel to Database

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have two workbooks with the same formatted columns: Name, Phone Number, and Place. My current thought process is I would merge both workbooks together and remove any duplicates, then move that master workbook to a database table in SSMS. However, I need a better way than manually checking for duplicates. Any direction? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the Remove Duplicates function on the Data tab in Excel?

Comment: ... @dwirony I am more confused on merging two workbooks

Comment: If the column formats are the same, you can simply copy + paste one into the other, stacked up. Then remove duplicates on the entire range.

Comment: @dwirony I have so many workbooks with a ton of data, that approach would be prone to error

Comment: Load all the records into a temporary table (including duplicates) then use a SQL query to fill your master table with the unique values. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)